# How can I mock an external function within a method in a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I need some help on mock.

I have following code in mymodule.py:

```
from someModule import external_function

class Class1(SomeBaseClass):
    def method1(self, arg1, arg2):
        external_function(param)
```

Now I have test code:

```
import mock
from django.test import TestCase

from mymodule import class1
class Class1Test(TestCase) 
    def test_method1:
        '''how can I mock external_function here?'''
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would write:

```
class Class1Test(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('mymodule.external_function')
    def test_method1(self, mock_external_function):
        pass
```

Looking at `mymodule` the function `external_function` is directly imported. Hence you need to mock `mymodule.external_function` as that's the function that will be called when `method1` is executed.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I was mocking wrong stuff. You straightened me up.